# Java while loop, looping more than it should

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm just making a simple Minesweeper game in my spare time. To place the mines I run the while loop until the total number of mines == the required number of mines for the level selected.

However, I always end up with more mines than expected! The only idea I have is that the while loop is running on multiple threads but I've tried to stop this and it still creates more mines than I want, I'm also not great with threads as I've not tried to use them specifically before.

I'm using Processing to make creating the window and drawing easier.

I've tried different things. Adding synchronized to loads of functions, the simple int count = 0; and then increment count every time a mine is placed somehow makes it worse?!?!

```
    private synchronized void placeMines() {
  ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  class placeThread implements Runnable {

    Grid grid;

    public placeThread(Grid grid) { this.grid = grid; }

    public void run() {

      final int mines = mode.mines;
      //int mCount = 0;
      while(this.grid.mineCount() < mines) {
        this.grid.addMine();
      }
      println(grid.mineCount());
    }

  }

  es.execute(new placeThread(this));

}

public synchronized boolean addMine() {
    int randX = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cols);
    int randY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * this.rows);
    Cell selected = getCell(randX, randY);
    if(selected.getValue() == 9) {
      selected.setValue(9);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public synchronized int mineCount() {

  int mCount = 0;
  for(ArrayList<Cell> row : this.cells) {
    for(Cell c : row) {
      if(c.isMine()) mCount++;
    }
  }
```

EDIT
I've change the code to use a for loop and modified the way in which a mine is added

```
    private synchronized void placeMines() {
  ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  class placeThread implements Runnable {

    Grid grid;

    public placeThread(Grid grid) { this.grid = grid; }

    public void run() {

      final int mines = mode.mines;

      ArrayList<Cell> cList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
      for(ArrayList<Cell> row : this.grid.cells) {
        cList.addAll(row);
      }

      for(int j = 0; j < mines; j++) {
        int randCell = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * cList.size());
        Cell selected = cList.get(randCell);
        if(this.grid.addMine(selected)) { cList.remove(selected); } else { j--; }
      }
      println(this.grid.mineCount());
    }

  }

  es.execute(new placeThread(this));

}

public synchronized boolean addMine(Cell c) {
    if(c.getValue() != 9) {
      c.setValue(9);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The Cell class (I've made my own event handling system because why not :p):

```
public class Cell extends Interactable {

  // value 0 -> 8 is the number of mines around the cell if cell is not a mine.
  // value = 9 when the cell is a mine
  int xPos, yPos, value, mark;
  //gridX and gridY are the coordinates of the cell relative to the grid.
  int gridX, gridY;
  boolean hidden = true;
  boolean flag = false;
  boolean wrong = false;
  Grid parent;

  //Drawing settings
  private int border;// = 4; //Border will be set in constructor as a percentage of the cellSize
  private int shade = 150;
  private int shown = 175;
  private int highlight = 200;

  public Cell(Grid parent,int gridX, int gridY) {
    this.parent = parent;

    this.gridX = gridX;
    this.gridY = gridY;
    this.createHitbox();
    this.updatePos();

    // Just for when I was testing, this is changed later
    this.value = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    this.parent.eHandler.register(this, EventList.MouseOver);
    this.parent.eHandler.register(this, EventList.MouseLeave);
    this.parent.eHandler.register(this, EventList.MouseClicked);
    this.parent.eHandler.register(this, EventList.MouseRightClicked);
  }

  public void die() {
    this.parent.eHandler.deregister(this, EventList.MouseOver);
    this.parent.eHandler.deregister(this, EventList.MouseLeave);
    this.parent.eHandler.deregister(this, EventList.MouseClicked);
    this.parent.eHandler.deregister(this, EventList.MouseRightClicked);
  }

  public void createHitbox() {
    this.hitBox = new HitBox(this.xPos, this.yPos, parent.cellSize, parent.cellSize);
  }

  public synchronized int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public synchronized void setValue(final int v) {
    this.value = v;
  }

  public void updatePos() {

    this.xPos = (parent.cellSize * gridX) + parent.xOffset;
    this.yPos = (parent.cellSize * gridY) + parent.yOffset;
    this.hitBox.x = this.xPos;
    this.hitBox.y = this.yPos;
    this.hitBox.w = parent.cellSize;
    this.hitBox.h = parent.cellSize;

    this.border = parent.cellSize / 10;

  }

  public synchronized boolean isMine() { return this.value == 9; }

  public void draw() {

    if(hidden) {
      stroke(this.highlight);
      strokeWeight(this.border);
      fill(this.shade);
      rect(this.xPos + this.border / 2, this.yPos + this.border / 2, this.parent.cellSize - this.border, this.parent.cellSize - this.border);
      if(this.flag) drawFlag();
    } else {
      noStroke();
      fill(this.shown);
      rect(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.parent.cellSize, this.parent.cellSize);
      drawValue();
    }

  }

  private void drawValue() {

    switch(this.value) {
      case 0:
        return;
      case 1:
        fill(10);
        break;
      case 2:
        fill(0, 0, 200);
        break;
      case 3:
        fill(0, 200, 0);
        break;
      case 4:
        fill(200, 0, 0);
        break;
      case 5:
        fill(200, 200, 0);
        break;
      case 6:
        fill(200, 100, 0);
        break;
      case 7:
        fill(100, 0, 200);
        break;
      case 8:
        fill(200, 0, 200);
        break;
      case 9:
        drawMine();
        return;
      default:
        return;
    }

    textSize(this.parent.cellSize);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(this.value, this.xPos + this.parent.cellSize / 2, this.yPos + this.parent.cellSize / 2);
    return;

  }

  private void drawMine() {
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(this.parent.cellSize / 2);
    point(this.xPos + this.parent.cellSize / 2, this.yPos + this.parent.cellSize / 2);
  }

  private void drawFlag() {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    if(wrong) stroke(0, 0, 255);
    strokeWeight(this.parent.cellSize / 2);
    point(this.xPos + this.parent.cellSize / 2, this.yPos + this.parent.cellSize / 2);
  }

  public int countMines() {
    if(this.isMine()) return 0;
    ArrayList<Cell> ns = parent.getNeighbours(this);
    int count = 0;
    for(Cell c : ns) {
      if(c.isMine()) count++;
    }
    return count;
  }

  public boolean allMinesFound() {
    if(this.isMine()) return false;
    ArrayList<Cell> ns = parent.getNeighbours(this);
    int mines = 0;
    int flags = 0;
    for(Cell c : ns) {
      if(c.isMine()) mines++;
      if(c.flag) flags++;
    }
    return mines == flags;
  }

  public void clearChain() {
    this.hidden = false;
    if(!this.allMinesFound()) return;
    for(Cell c : parent.getNeighbours(this)) {
      if(c.flag) continue;
      boolean wasHidden = c.hidden;
      c.reveal(false);
      if(c.isMine()) return;
      if(c.value == 0 && wasHidden) c.clearChain();
    }

  }

  public void reveal(boolean cce) {
    this.hidden = false;
    if(this.value == 9) {
      //GAMEOVER! MINE!
      this.GameOver();
      return;
    }
    if (this.value == 0 && cce == true) {
      clearChain();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onMouseOverEvent() {
    this.shade += 20;
    this.highlight += 20;
  }

  @Override
  public void onMouseClickedEvent() {
    if(!this.hitBox.test(mouseX, mouseY) || !hidden) return;
    if(this.flag) return;
    this.reveal(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMouseRightClickedEvent() {
    if(!this.hitBox.test(mouseX, mouseY)) return;
    //Mark Loop
    if(!hidden) {
      clearChain();
      return;
    }
    this.flag = !this.flag;
    int fCount = 0;
    for(ArrayList<Cell> row : grid.cells) {
      for(Cell c : row) {
        if(c.flag) fCount++;
      }
    }
    this.parent.parent.flagCount = fCount;
    if(this.parent.parent.flagCount >= this.parent.parent.mines) {
      this.parent.verifyFlags();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onMouseLeaveEvent() {
    this.shade -= 20;
    this.highlight -= 20;
  }

  private void GameOver() {
    this.parent.parent.GameOver();
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code has many logical problems.  Both the add and count methods do not appear to be working at all.

Comment: We need **the shortest code necessary to reproduce**.

Comment: @PeterRader the issue is the while loop on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve completely your problem but I will give you some pointers.

The general logic around the `while` statement is ok. You have an exit condition that should be `true` when `addMine()` would add the number of required mines :

```
 while(this.grid.mineCount() < mines) {
    this.grid.addMine();
  }
```

But note that if `addMine()` and `mineCount()` are incorrectly implemented, it will not work as you expect.   You don't show the `Cell` code that could explain the issue.

> To place the mines I run the while loop until the total number of
>   mines == the required number of mines for the level selected.

Using a `while` statement for a number of iteration known early is not relevant.
Generally you use it as you don't know the number of iteration that you have to do.
Using a `loop` seems more appropriate if you know this number :

```
for (int i=0; i< mines; i++) {
    this.grid.addMine();
}
```

As as a side note,  `selected.setValue(9);` seems useless here :

```
if(selected.getValue() == 9) {
  selected.setValue(9);
  return true;
}
```

In conclusion, you should probably start by little steps before trying to make the whole application to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The addMine() code is there, its sandwiched in the middle of the code snippet so it's easy to miss. I did initially use a for loop, but the way I add a mine uses a random grid x y value which could be chosen a second time causing too few mines to be placed. Also thanks for the selected.getValue() == 9 spot, it was meant to be !=

Comment: @GTBebbo You are welcome :) Sorry it is not addMine() but `Cell` class I would refer to.

Comment: I've edited my code to use a for loop and edited the original post to show this and the Cell class

Comment: Also forgot to mention, the value of 9 means that the cell is a mine, as you cannot have 9 mines around a cell.

Comment: Found the issue, the loop wasn't at fault, but it was setting the values of some of the cells to 9 when the cell was created. But thanks for spotting the other issues as well!